# create multipe telephone directory records in python using list and dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm creating Telephone Directory program by using python, first of all i'm new to python here i created class and declare global list and dict, because i want to store when i call testcreate function we enter name and phone that will stored in list and that list will be stored in dict through save function. To show telephone directory data just call getdata function, but its not working any help thank in advance

```
class testdl():
    testlist=[]
    testdic={}      
    def testcreate():
        name = input("enter name : ")
        phone = input("enter phone : ")
        testdl.save(name,phone)
    def save(n,p):
        testdl.testlist[n]=p
        testdl.testdic = testdl.testlist
    def getdata():
        print(testdl.testdic)


>>> tdll = testdl()
>>> tdll.testcreate()

**Error Message :**
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
        tdll.testcreate()
    TypeError: testcreate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>> testdl.testcreate()
enter name : srikanth
enter phone : 1234567890

**Error Message :** 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#82>", line 1, in <module>
        testdl.testcreate()
      File "<pyshell#79>", line 7, in testcreate
        testdl.save(name,phone)
      File "<pyshell#79>", line 9, in save
        testdl.testlist[n]=p
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: like it said,need a argument(we always use `self`).And you should use a dict to save it not a list.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA : can you elaborate more briefly because i'm new to python and i'm searching for 2 days for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1:
Every method in a class needs self as first argument, which refers to the current instance

```
def testcreate(self):
    name = input("enter name : ")
    phone = input("enter phone : ")
    self.save(name,phone)
```

Error 2:

```
def save(self, n,p):
     self.testlist[n]=p
```

lists accept only ints as indices

---

**Errors you will get**

Error 3:
`self.testlist` is empty => IndexError: Index not found

Error 4:
a list is not a dictionary
(in save())

```
testdl.testdic = testdl.testlist
```

Possible solution

```
class testdl():
    testdic={}      
    def testcreate(self, ):
        name = input("enter name : ")
        phone = input("enter phone : ")
        self.save(name,phone)

    def save(self, n,p):
        self.testlist[n]=p

    def getdata(self, n):
        print(self.testdic[n])
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently,your function can be a staticmethod and there is no need create a class.If you really want to create a class:

```
class Testdl:
    def __init__(self): # initialize the value
        self.testlist=[]
        self.testdic={}
        self.name = None
        self.phone = None
    def testcreate(self):
        self.name = input("enter name : ")
        self.phone = input("enter phone : ")
        self.save()
    def save(self):
        self.testdic[self.name] = self.phone # maybe you need a dict to save them not a list
        self.testlist.append(self.testdic) # then you append it in the list
    def getdata(self):
        print(self.testdic)

testdl = Testdl() # create a instance
testdl.testcreate() # call the function
testdl.getdata() # print the data
```

If you want to record three groups of data,use:

```
testdl = Testdl()
for i in range(3):
    testdl.testcreate()
testdl.getdata()
```